# Incoporating HTML5/Bootstrap theme into a phoenix framework app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, phoenix-framework, elixir

I am trying to incoporate a html5/boostrap theme I bought into a phoenix framework app I'm working on. The theme has regular html files (one for each page), js, css, font and images folders. I moved the theme specific js and css files to the `web/static/js` and `web/static/css`. I moved the third party js and css files into the respective folders under `web/static/vendor/js` and `web/static/vendor/css`, These files include for (`css: animate.css, bootstrap.css, flaticon.css, font-awesome.css, hover.css, responsive.css, resolution-slider.css, owl.css`), (`js: bootstrap.min.js, jquery.js, bxslider.js, revolution.min.js, validate.js`).

The images for the app was moved to `web/static/assets/images` and the graphics can be found at `web/statc/assets`. I have not made any changes to brunch-config.js.

I have managed to get app.html.eex and index.html.eex to adopt the theme. At the moment when I access localhost:4000, I see the following on the console `[info] GET /css/assets/timer.png [debug] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /css/assets/timer.png (RocfDev.Router)`

I tracked the timer.png resource request to the file `web/statc/vendor/css/resolution-slider.css`. The css code in the file is `background:url(assets/timer.png`).

timer.png is actually located in `web/static/assets`. Phoenix seems to be able to serve all the images and graphics ok except timer.png.

My question is why is phoenix trying to serve `timer.png` from the wrong folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`background:url(assets/timer.png)` - the URL here is relative, so the browser thinks that it should look for timer.png file in `#{path_to_directory_of_source_css_file}/assets/timer.png`.

Changing given line to `background:url(/assets/timer.png)` should help.